# Query DB table and convert to DataFrame ok, but data is truncated when exported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am querying a MySQL DB and fetching data from a table.  My code looks like this.

```
# login creds, etc., etc., 

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")
```

Everything seems ok, I guess, but when I export the data to a text file.

```
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(myresult)
#print(df)
df=str(df)

outF = open("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test.txt", "w")
outF.writelines(df)
outF.close()
```

Comment: try removing the `df=str(df)` line, and df.to_csv or similar to write to file instead.

Comment: Yeah, that works fine.  I have actually used that in the past.  I forgot about it.  Too many things going on these days.  Thanks a bunch!!